# Jquery drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a jquery drop down i am trying to make: http://jsfiddle.net/qYMq4/2/

Basically i just want a div to drop down when a user mouses over a link and stay down unless i mouse away from the link or over the dropped down div and then away from the div. So it is almost like a standard drop down menu that you see in alot of website navigation, but this just has a bit of animation so it doesn't appear instantly.

I'm finding it terribly difficult, as you can see it doesn't quite function correctly. Any adivce? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

**[You can see a working demo of the following here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz9Ce/)**

I prefer `mouseenter`<sup>[[DOCS]](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)</sup> and `mouseleave`<sup>[DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)</sup> in this situation as it behaves better when hovering over children.  I restructured your HTML so that the hover is over the parent div of the link, so that when you hover over the gray area that slides down it's not considered a `mouseleave` as follows:

```
<div class="mask-layer">
    <a class="top-link-cart" href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Test</a>
    <div class="slidedown">div should close if user moves mouse away from test (but not to the gray area) or away from the gray area. The .mouseout function doesn't appear to work. </div>
</div>
```

I then restructured your Javascript to use `.mask-layer` for the hover events, and simplified the animation with `slideUp`<sup>[[DOCS]](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)</sup> and `slideDown`<sup>[[DOCS]](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)</sup> as follows:

```
$('.slidedown').hide();
$('div.mask-layer').mouseenter(function() { // enter animation
    $('.slidedown').slideDown(600);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.slidedown').slideUp(600);
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: one small issue in your code. when you leave slidedown div and reenter again immediately, it just slideup & down multiple times....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) and [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) methods - they're a littler easier to work with.  You'll also want to use the windowSetTimeout.  A lesser known feature is that it returns a number which will allow you to cancel the timeout.  You can use that to keep the div open in the event the user scrolls down onto it.  Some inspiration for this approach borrowed from here:  http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slidedown').hide();
    var timeout = 500;
    var closetimer = 0;

    $('a.top-link-cart, .slidedown').mouseover( function(){
        cancel_timer();
        $('.slidedown').slideDown(1000);
    });

    $('a.top-link-cart, .slidedown').mouseout( function(){
        closetimer = window.setTimeout(function(){$('.slidedown').slideUp(1000)}, timeout);
      });

function cancel_timer(){
 if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;
   }
 }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P567S/7/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code example. I can see the logic behind putting a.top-link and .slidedown as target of the .mouseout function. However that makes the .slidedown div slide back up before the user has a chance to move the mouse over it. Is there a way to make .slidedown stay open but only if user mouses into the slidedown area?

Comment: updated my answer with one that should work better using timeouts

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a click action dropdown menu here it is

```
//toggle navbar on click.
$('//my link').click(function(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
$('//sub menu container').toggle();

});

//to close dropdown menu when clicked out it.
$(document).click(function() {
$('//sub menu container').hide();
});
```

hope it works for you..... !!